# Is there a way to download the rendered view of a google motion-chart as a .png?

Tags: api, google-visualization

I am using Google motion-charts in a web-site developed in python/django. Is there a way to save the rendered view of a google motion-chart as an image (server-side)?

For the more basic chart types - such as scatter diagrams - the command `chart.download('scatter-random-marker-sizes.png')`
works fine, but I have not found an equivalent for motion charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (they are all flash).  but you can save and restore the state of a visualization you create (it's saved in a string, which you could store locally).  See Setting Initial State in the doc:

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html

Comment: Thx. We are now working on a rather complex alternative: Using amCharts to render a similar chart to the motion chart parameters - and then exporting that chart.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Trend Compass -- it exports your chart directly to Powerpoint.

Trend Compass is a new concept in viewing statistics and trends by 
displaying data in an animated way by displaying in one chart 5 axis 
(X, Y, Time, Bubble size & Bubble color) instead of just the traditional 
X and Y axis. It could be used in analysis, research, presentation etc.

This is a bank link to compare deposits, withdrawals and numbers of
customers for different branches over time (all in 1 chart):
http://www.epicsyst.com/test/v2/bank-trx/

You can download a trial version. It has a feature to export
EXE, PPS, HTML and AVI files. The most impressive is the AVI since you
can record Audio/Video for the charts you create.

http://www.epicsyst.com/TrendCompass/FreeVersion/TrendCompassv1.2.2.zip